# How does Slark's autoattacks go trough Pugna's Decrepify?

Tags: dota-2

I've just played a match (62958817) with [Pugna](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Pugna) which had a enemy [Slark](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Slark). In multiple occasions, when he was about to attack me, I'd use [Decrepify](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Pugna#Decrepify) (immunity to autoattacks + can't autoattack + 40% more magic damage received) to defend myself, but it seems that either applying it to him or myself is ineffective, if not increasing the damage I take (when applied to me). While reading trough [Slark](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Slark)'s abilities, I couldn't find any hint of why would his autoattacks be counted as magic damage.
His build was constituted by the following items:

- Assault Cuirass
- Power Treads
- Bottle
- Sange and Yasha
- Skull Basher
- Shadow Blade

None of these appear to give magic damage in their tooltip. It's also worth noting that while he did cause normal damage, I wasn't affected by Skull Basher at all.

How did he bypass that immunity?

Comment: Are you sure these were auto attacks ? My guess is that it happened while he was under his ulti and you couldn't see what he was doing, but it's probably a dark pact + decrepify amplify damage that made you think he was auto attacking. Not 100% sure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Slark's Dark Pact removes the Ethereal debuff that Decrep applies, allowing him to attack you.